# Apparent incorrect use of renderUI in R Shiny for interactive dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an Rshiny dashboard and am working to integrate some of shiny's more interactive features, and am currently working with the renderUI function, which (should, I believe) create additional widgets / input parameters based on the value of another input parameter. I am running into a simple error, but am having difficulty debugging. Below is a demo with the relevant code:

```
choices = c('All', 'None')
names(choices) = choices
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme('united'),

     # create permanent input for shot chart type (should be 5 options)
     selectInput(inputId = 'choice.input', label = 'Select a choice', multiple = FALSE,
                 choices = choices, selected = 'All'),

     uiOutput('secondinput')

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  if(input$choice.input == 'All') {

    my.second.input <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
    names(my.second.input) <- my.second.input

    # player parameter for player whose shot chart will be shown
    output$secondinput <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = 'another.input', label = 'Check this input', multiple = FALSE,
                  choices = my.second.input, selected = 'a')
    })
  }
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here - I thought my use of renderUI() in the server function, with the names matching (output$secondinput, uiOutput('secondinput')), was corrent, but this is throwing an error at me...

Note that my full code has several options for choice.input, and I would like to have an if() case in the server for each of the (4-5) choice.input() values. Any help with what's wrong here is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT - to clarify, the select input choice.input, with label 'Select a Choice', should be displaying always. When this input is set to 'All', then I'd like for an additional input, secondinput, to be displayed. If choice.input is not set to 'All', then I don't want the second input to be displayed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that works. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, it was a bit hard to tell, but hopefully you can take it from there.

```
choices = c('All', 'None')
names(choices) = choices
ui <- fluidPage(
  # create permanent input for shot chart type (should be 5 options)
  selectInput(inputId = 'choice.input', label = 'Select a choice', multiple = FALSE,
              choices = choices, selected = 'All'),
  uiOutput('secondinput')
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # player parameter for player whose shot chart will be shown
  output$secondinput <- renderUI({
    if(input$choice.input == 'All') {

      my.second.input <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
      names(my.second.input) <- my.second.input
      selectInput(inputId = 'another.input', label = 'Check this input', multiple = FALSE,
                  choices = my.second.input, selected = 'a')    

    } else{
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The error that happened told you that you're trying to access a reactive value without a reactive context. You were trying to access the input value (which is reactive) outside of a render function or an observe function, which are reactive contexts.

If you don't understand what that means, I highly suggest you read this section on a shiny tutorial I wrote, [reactivity 101](https://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/#10-reactivity-101).

The second issue here was that you were trying to "nest" a render function, which *can* work but is the wrong way to think about it, and suggests that you may not really grasp the concept of reactivity and render functions fully. Notice that I moved the render function to the outside, that's generally the correct way to program in shiny. If you have a bit of time, I suggest watching Joe Cheng's (the author of shiny) videos "effective reactive programming I and II" from the 2016 shiny conference https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/